# Latex mathematical equations in SVG elements

Tags: d3.js, svg, latex

Is the a straightforward way to embed latex mathematical equations (typesetting) in a SVG element, e.g. labels in D3.js or within a SVG text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use MathML by embedding HTML in a `<foreignObject>` element.  However that would only work in browsers. And only for [browsers that support MathML](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mathml).

Otherwise you would need to search out some other utilities such as those suggested here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/33196/how-to-convert-latex-equations-to-svg